¿Como persistir 100k en el menor tiempo posible. Utilizando Java, spring boot, sql server?
En este momento estoy con un reto de persistir 100k registros o más en el menor tiempo posible.
El proyecto que estoy desarrollando lo estoy haciendo con java 17 y spring boot 3.2.5
Dentro de mi proyecto estoy manejando reactividad, programación funcional para manejar este flujo de datos.
Toda la data que deseo persistir lo estoy haciendo en SQL SERVER.
mi idea para persistir en la base ha sido hacerlo mediante batchs y lo he configurado ya que procese de 1k, 5k, pero el tiempo sigue siendo demasiado.
//Primera opción para guardar en base
private void persistOrderItems(
      Integer batchSize,
      List<SqlServerOrderItemEntity> sqlServerOrderItemEntitiesToPersist
  ) {
    log.info("|-> persist order items started");
    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
        "INSERT INTO business_banking_model_order.order_item (version, data, order_id, unique_order_id, sequence_reference_number) "
            + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
        sqlServerOrderItemEntitiesToPersist,
        batchSize,
        (PreparedStatement ps, SqlServerOrderItemEntity sqlServerOrderItemEntity) -> {
          sqlServerOrderItemEntity.setData(jsonHelper.toJson(sqlServerOrderItemEntity));
          ps.setInt(1, 0);
          ps.setString(2, sqlServerOrderItemEntity.getData());
          ps.setString(3, sqlServerOrderItemEntity.getOrderId());
          ps.setLong(4, sqlServerOrderItemEntity.getUniqueOrderId());
          ps.setLong(5, sqlServerOrderItemEntity.getSequenceReferenceNumber());
        }
    );
  }

//Segunda opción para guardar en base
private void persistOrderItems(
      Integer batchSize,
      List<SqlServerOrderItemEntity> sqlServerOrderItemEntitiesToPersist
  ) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO business_banking_model_order.order_item (version, data, order_id, unique_order_id,            sequence_reference_number) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    List<Object[]> batchArgs = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>(1000));
    sqlServerOrderItemEntitiesToPersist.parallelStream().forEach(entity -> {
      entity.setData(jsonHelper.toJson(entity));
      batchArgs.add(new Object[]{
          0,
          entity.getData(),
          entity.getOrderId(),
          entity.getUniqueOrderId(),
          entity.getSequenceReferenceNumber()
      });
      if (batchArgs.size() >= batchSize) {
        synchronized (batchArgs) {
          if (batchArgs.size() >= batchSize) {
            jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, new ArrayList<>(batchArgs));
            batchArgs.clear();
          }
        }
      }
    });
    if (!batchArgs.isEmpty()) {
      jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, batchArgs);
    }
  }

  @NonNull
  @Transactional
  @Override
  public Mono<Void> saveAll(
      List<SqlServerOrderItemEntity> sqlServerOrderItemEntities,
      Integer batchSize
  ) {
    log.info("|-> Persist to database started");
    return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> persistOrderItems(batchSize, sqlServerOrderItemEntities))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
        .then()
        .doOnSuccess(response -> log.info("|-> Persist to database finished successfully"))
        .doOnError(error -> log.error(
                "|-> Persist to database finished with error. ErrorDetail: {}",
                error.getMessage()
            )
        )
        .onErrorMap(throwable -> new OrderItemSavingException());
  }


Tendrías que leer sobre como usar parámetros de tipo tabla. Para eso necesitarías un procedimiento almacenado. ¿Por qué guardas 100K a la vez? ¿No sería mejor usar una herramienta ETL o ELT para esto? ¿Qué clase de sistema inserta tantos registros a la vez?

te recomiendo usar una funcionalidad llama cursores.... en tus procedimientos almacenados. Si ya saben que todo se ejecuta 100 veces más rápido del lado de base de datos y tercos en no querer hacer procedimientos almacenados.
